# flat file mapping to json

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

I have a flat file in below format:

```
value1|value2|Value5|...|ValueN
```

I would like to match those values using json schema name.

Example Schema

```
{
object : { "name1:Value1",
"name2:Value2",
"name3:Value3",
.
.
},object : { "name1:Value1",
"name2:Value2",
"name3:Value3",
.
.
},
```

how to map those flat file values to json schema.

Comment: There are libraries like GSON which may serve your purpose. Here you go https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jobj1=new JSONObject();
JSONObject jobj2=new JSONObject();
JSONObject jobj3=new JSONObject();

jobj2.put("v1":"a");
jobj2.put("v2":"b");

jobj3.put("v3":"a");
jobj3.put("v4":"b");

obj1.put("object1":jobj2);
obj1.put("object1":jobj3);
```